# iPhone - Outlook 2010 sync'd items

Tags: iphone, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Outlook 2010, or the fact that I don't have an Exchange box, or the fact that I have two MAPI mailboxes (both using Outlook Live Connector), or something else... so let me just describe the situation.

iTunes says that I'm sync'ing happily, all the Calendar, Contact items, Notes... and if I have changed several things I get the "you're changing more than 5% of items" warning, persuading me that the sync'ing is working.

I just can't find those items on my PC. They're not sync'ing with either of my Live accounts (Calendar or Contacts), and I can't find any track of anything. iTunes says I have Calendar folders called "" and "Calendar", but doesn't show any Contact groups at all.

So how do I find out where they're going to... or change where they're going to... or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded to iOS4, and now it syncs! All my Contacts are fine, and I imagine Mail would sync fine too, except that I have a separate app I use for that.

BUT!!! Despite telling me it would Merge calendars, I lost all the calendar entries that were in my iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

here is also tip for outlook on iphone, see [how to sync outlook with iphone](http://www.phonesappstabs.com/how-to-setup-outlook-email-on-ipad-or-iphone/)

http://www.phonesappstabs.com/how-to-setup-outlook-email-on-ipad-or-iphone/

hope it helps you....

Comment: Please don't just link, but include the relevant information from the link. Read [answer], please. Other than that, how does this answer the question?